# Can we request queries for the SE Data Explorer on Meta?

Tags: support, meta, site-recommendation, data-explorer

I don't know how to effectively use the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/). I was wondering how to see the top 100 most [unsung users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero).

What I mean by top 100 is a list ordered by biggest % of zero accepted answers in descending order.

I am not sure if it's on topic on the main site and not even sure if asking for such queries is allowed here, hence the question title. <del>I think the answer is learn SQL and stop complaining</del> but I want to be sure whether is valid or not.

Comment: I don't think it's valid. Otherwise it will fill the meta with such questions which isn't the purpose of meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think questions asking specifically for a Data Explorer query would be off-topic on Meta. There are two alternatives though:

- You could just ask a question on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (or here, if your question is specifically about Stack Overflow) and leave it up to the community to answer it with or without writing a DE query.
- You could attempt a query on your own, and ask about it on Stack Overflow if you run into problems.

Comment: These sort of questions belong on [meta.se] instead, in my opinion.

Comment: @Cupcake Right! Forgot where I was for a moment. I'll update my answer.