# Can SEDE be used to compare SE sites?

Tags: discussion, support, data-explorer, stack-exchange

Is there any way to use SEDE to query multiple SE sites simultaneously?

There are a number of things that this would be useful for. You could try to find cross-site duplicates, see which site has higher average scores, etc.

So if it's possible, how would I do it? Otherwise, would this be a feasible feature to request?

Comment: Shouldn't that be better asked on [Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, [here I have one example among many similar ones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261546/downloading-all-my-questions-with-the-answerer-names/261594#261594) but keep in mind that you're still limited to the 120 seconds before a query runs out. You can only run very simple queries, don't try things that do a full-table scan on the posts table....

Comment: @rene I'm not very experienced with SQL. What do you mean by a "full-table scan"? Anyways, I'll usually abort the query before it times out.

Comment: @Laurel if the database engine has no index that can be used to filter your result set it needs to read every record. For the posts table on SO that almost never ends well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if that is true (and I found [this already](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268796/can-we-request-queries-for-the-se-data-explorer-on-meta)) maybe either you or me should write a meta post to verify and/or update the tag wiki to make that clear.

Comment: @rene I see your point. I won't open a new question on Meta SE.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I belong to MSE, so I could've posted it there. I'm asking for code, so I though I'd get better results here.

Comment: @Laurel Regarding SEDE code Meta Stack Overflow might differ from other SE sites (because of different data models). It's a bit borderline, I actually don't know where to ask for such query but _Meta Meta_.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, that is possible.<sup>1</sup>

In [T-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510741.aspx) you can switch between databases or link to a database. To know which databases there are you can run this query:

```
select name
from sys.databases
```

The tables are always in the `dbo` schema. To determine which tags are common between Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault you can run this join over three tables from three databases (Stack Overflow is the currentdb here):

```
select sot.tagname 
from tags sot 
inner join superuser.dbo.tags sut 
        on sut.tagname = sot.tagname
inner join serverfault.dbo.tags sft
        on sft.tagname = sot.tagname
```

Finaly you can do some fancy scripting with dynamic sql and cursors, in this example to get an overview of the number of users per site:

```
-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE

declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #all_users ( site nvarchar(250)
                            , cnt int
                            );
                            
open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +';
    insert into #all_users 
    select '''+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +''', count(*) from users';
    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select * from #all_users
```

You can find the above SQL statements working (as multiple resultsets) in [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/477550).

Keep in mind that over on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer) there are a lot more questions and answers about SEDE, including the one that explains that [client-side sorting is enabled only for resultsets <= 5000](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213422/158100) which is something I just learned...

<sub>1. [From Tim Stone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321643/can-sede-be-used-to-compare-se-sites/321644?noredirect=1#comment336447_321644): (There's also native support for running the same query across multiple sites, but it's not enabled on the public instance)</sub>

Comment: This is great, but why are there no arrows on the labels to change the sort?

Comment: (There's also native support for running the same query across multiple sites, but it's not enabled on the public instance)

Comment: @Laurel If you have more than 5000 result records, client-side sorting will be disabled

Comment: @TimStone Thanks for telling me!